# What exactly is allocated to the stack of a function when it has a reference to a variable as its parameter?

Tags: rust

We read in [Ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) how a function keeps its parameter data in the stack. That may be a value in case of primitive type or a pointer to the data residing on the heap. Now how is the parameter represented in the stack when it is a reference to something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, a reference, ie `&'a T` is basically just a pointer. The difference is that you have the memory safety guaranteed by `Rust`'s static compilation rules. As in, the rules you just read about in that chapter. When you pass a parameter to, say a function with a signature like this:

```rust
struct UnitBar(i32);
fn foo(data: &UnitBar);
```

and you call it like so:

```rust
struct UnitBar(i32);
fn main() {
    let bar = UnitBar(0); //Sizeof bar is sizeof i32
    foo(&bar);
}
```

Rust will allocate a `UnitBar` which is 4 bytes in this case. Then, it will allocate a pointer to `bar`, which is the same size as the native pointers in the computer, or more idiomatically the same size as a `usize` in rust. Note here that there is no difference between a pointer and a reference **at the memory level**. At the static compilation level, or in your code, there are static compile-time checks to make sure that your code follows rust's rules. From here, the `data` parameter in `fn foo` will be represented as a pointer in memory. This **will not** copy the data that it's pointing to every time that it is passed on to another function or scope.

Although not guaranteed to look like this, as the compiler can move things around in memory to produce more efficient programs, this is pretty much how it works.

---

As a side note, there are 3 special cases:

1. The case of the slice. `&[T]` will take two "pointer lengths" to store. Why? Because a `&[T]` is a special type, where it contains a `*const T` and a `usize`. It is the c equivalent of this:

```
struct SliceReference {
    *const T data;
    size_t length;
}
```

2. The other (similar case) is a `&str`. This is essentially a `&[u8]`, so it also follows the memory model above, but instead assures you that all the characters it contains, ie, the configuration of bytes stored inside of it, are UTF-8.
3. This is the last case, where there are trait objects. Ie, `&dyn std::fmt::Debug`. The size of this is again, two `usize`s or two `size_t`s for the c/c++ programmers. There is the first pointer which points to the data, and the second one points to the vtable where the function signatures for each of its respective functions are stored.

Note that *all* of the above counts towards things which are essentially the same as a `&T` in memory:

```
Option<&T>     -|
Box<T>          |
Rc<T>           - These all have the same size as `&T`
Arc<Mutex<T>>   |
struct Foo(&T) -|
```

---

As an edit, [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ebde405703cb267f97243516cb896743) is proof that these are all the same size.

Comment: Are you sure that the smart pointers (`Rc`, `Arc`, etc) have the same size as `&T`? They all have additional state beyond that of just the encapsulated data.

Comment: @apemanzilla Yeah, I would have believed that at first but they oddly do have the same size. Look at the edit I posted.

Comment: @apemanzilla `Rc` and `Arc` store the refcount inside the "box", in-line with the `T`. They don't have separate data pointer and refcount pointer like you might find inside a C++ `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Note: Your 3 special cases are generally known as *dynamically sized types*. There is no guarantee made on the layout of DSTs, and there have been proposals in the past to have `&(Add +Sub)` for example being represented as two v-ptrs + one data-ptr.